# Qt qmake change build directory path

Tags: qt, qmake

How can I include an external library in my project and keep the build inside of the project?
For example:

```
myproject.pro

TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
        ../../libs/lib1 \
        ../../libs/lib2 \
        app
```

This is resulting in a build structure like that:

```
build/
├─ myproject/
│  ├─ kit1/
│  │  ├─ app/
│  ├─ kit2/
│  │  ├─ app/
│  ├─ libs/
│  │  ├─ lib1/
│  │  ├─ lib2/
```

So, this leads to incompatible linking.
The build structure that I would like to have is something like that:

```
build/
├─ myproject/
│  ├─ kit1/
│  │  ├─ libs/
│  │  │  ├─ lib1/
│  │  │  ├─ lib2/
│  │  ├─ app/
│  ├─ kit2/
│  │  ├─ libs/
│  │  │  ├─ lib1/
│  │  │  ├─ lib2/
│  │  ├─ app/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell qmake that app depends on lib1 and lib2. Rewrite qmake project file like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
 
  SUBDIRS = \
            lib1 \   # sub-project names
            lib2 \
            app
 
  
  lib1.subdir = ../../libs/lib1
  lib2.subdir = ../../libs/lib2
  app.subdir = app 
  app.depends = lib1 lib2
```

You can try also force qmake to keep order during compilation by adding

```
 CONFIG += ordered
```

to your original project file.

**[EDIT]**

I suppose you are using QtCreator to build the project, so `$$OUT_PWD` variable is defined.
You can copy the compiled libraries into desired destination. Put in your **app.pro** something like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += \
              ../../../libs/lib1 \
              ../../../libs/lib2

SOURCES += <list of sources>

LIBS += \
   -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib1 -llib1 \
   -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib2 -llib2


QMAKE_PRE_LINK += $(MKDIR) $$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib1; cp -d ../../../libs/lib1/*so* $$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib1;
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += $(MKDIR) $$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib2; cp -d ../../../libs/lib2/*so* $$OUT_PWD/../libs/lib2/
```

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately, the build path is not changing. Libs build path is still on the same level of the kit